# Parse SimpleDateFormat of RSS

Tags: android, rss, feed, simpledateformat

I have an app that read a rss from a website `(Tue, 17 Mar 2015 12:41:41 +0000)`. I get this format date `(Tue Mar 17 12:41:41 GMT 2015)` and I want to obtain this: `Tuesday 17 March` in **spanish** `Martes, 17 Marzo`.

I'm trying differents forms, but I can't parse de date.

This is my code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The porcion code where I get the data of the xml parse:

```
else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
    noticia.setFecha(formatter.parse(""+property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()));
```

Comment: Which date format do you get from the RSS feed - the one with the timezone or the one without?  If it's the one without then the Z timezone specifier in the format will cause the exception to be thrown.  Conversely, if you don't include the Z format specifier, SimpleDateFormat will parse dates both with and without a timezone present.

Comment: I get the correct timezone (Tue, 17 Mar 2015 12:41:41 +0000), but I want to parse in this date Martes, 17 Marzo. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of `Locale.ENGLISH` use `new Locale("es","ES")`.  Because you have no year in your Spanish date string, the parsed date will be `Tue Mar 17 00:00:00 GMT 1970`

Comment: If I do DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", new Locale("es","ES"));   I have this error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 17 Mar 2015 17:15:52 +0000" (at offset 0)

Comment: OK - I'm confused now!  Are you trying to parse an English date?  (I think you are in which case use `Locale.ENGLISH` and a date formatter created with the format `EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss`).  Are you wanting to display the date in Spanish?  If so create a second SimpleDateFormatter using `new Locale("es","ES")` and a format of `EEEE, dd MMMM` and the `format(Date)` method on the second formatter will produce `Martes, 17 Marzo`

Comment: Hi, I try this and when I try to emulate the app in the phone is crash:          DateFormat formatter =
                new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat formatte =
                new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        formatter.format(formatte);

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet parses the English date `Tue, 17 Mar 2015 12:41:41 +0000` and outputs it in a Spanish representation `Martes, 17 Marzo`

```
        try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("Tue, 17 Mar 2015 12:41:41 +0000");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM", new Locale("es","ES"));
        System.out.println("Date: " + sdf2.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I get Unhandled exception:java.text.ParseException in this line: sdf.parse("Tue, 17 Mar 2015 12:41:41 +0000");

Comment: @Simpson This is the string parameter to SimpleDateFormat
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
For you date.
And [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the documentation to search how to create your own parse string